# cygwinのemacs24での透過方法を教えてください

Tags: emacs, cygwin

windows7で、cygwinと同時にインストールしたemacsを使っていますが背景を透過できません。
cygwin version : CYGWIN_NT-6.1
emacs version : 
    GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.14.13) of 2015-06-23 on desktop-new

Xの起動は以下のコマンドで、
    run xwin -multiwindow -clipboard
~/.emacs.d/init.elへは以下を記述しています。
    (set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha 20)

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: まずは cygwin の terminal(シェル)で、`xprop -root | grep -E 'SUPPORTED.*OPACITY'` を実行して見て下さい。何も出力されない場合、背景の透過はできません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。何も出力されませんでした。。。
minttyが透過できたので何となくできるもんだと思っていましたがそうではないのですね。

Window Manager(の設定？)によってはできるのでしょうか。
もしくは、そこらへんの情報があるサイトを教えていただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: mintty は Windows アプリケーションですので…。Cygwin パッケージには XtoW という window manager があるそうです。[この画像](http://x.cygwin.com/screenshots/cygx-xtow-alphademo-20130805.png)を見る限り、背景透過をサポートしている様です。